# Using py.test --cov from inside setup.py pytest.main

Tags: python, pytest, test-coverage

I'm developing a package with some testing.

**Working with CMD:**

```
py.test --cov my_pkg
```

I get the results with covarage:

```
--------------- coverage: platform win32, python 2.7.9-final-0 ----------------
Name                            Stmts   Miss  Cover
---------------------------------------------------
my_pkg\__init__       8      0   100%
my_pkg\general        2      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                              10      0   100%
```

**Fails:**

when trying to integrate it inside `pytest.main()` and running with:

`python setup.py test`

with the following:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0
rootdir: C:\Users\kobi.kalif\Projects\automation_utilities, inifile:
plugins: cov, xdist

ERROR: file not found: --cov my_pkg
```

**Relevant Code:**

```
class PyTest(test_command):
    """class py.test for the testing

    """
    user_options = []

    def __init__(self, dist, **kw):
        test_command.__init__(self, dist, **kw)
        self.pytest_args = ["--cov my_pkg"]

.....

    def run_tests(self):
        # import here, cause outside the eggs aren't loaded
        import pytest
        err_no = pytest.main(self.pytest_args)
        sys.exit(err_no)
```

**Question:**

How can i run tests with coverage from inside the `setup.py` file `pytest.main`?

Comment: Have you tried passing just a string `self.pytest_args = "--cov my_pkg"` or passing them as two arguments: `self.pytest_args = ["--cov", "my_pkg"]`?

Comment: If you use `setup.cfg`, you could add `addopts = --cov=my_pkg` to the section **[tool:pytest]**. Be careful: the correct name of section depends on version of `pytest`, so, please, check the [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#command-line-options-and-configuration-file-settings)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code) you should either do:

```
self.pytest_args = ["--cov", "my_pkg"]
```

or:

```
self.pytest_args = "--cov my_pkg"
```